# Decompositon of Tangent Bundles

Tags: algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry

Let $X\subset \mathbb P^n$ be a compact manifold over $\mathbb C$, $Y\subset X$ be a submanifold. We know there is a smooth decomposition
$$T_X|_Y=T_Y \oplus N_{Y/X}$$

My question is:

> is there some known condition to ensure this decomposition to be holomorphic?

In particular I want to know if $Y$ is a hyperplane section, will the decomposition be holomorphic?

Comment: The splitting is holomorphic for a hyperplane and that is the only time it will be.

Comment: @Mohan Any reference about this?

Comment: It is too elementary to have been mentioned separately, but the necessary exact sequences can be found in any Algebraic Geometry book.